# REST APIのレスポンスパラメータで値が無い場合にnullと空文字とどっちにするべきか？

Tags: api

バックエンドのAPIを開発していて、APIによってはレスポンスのパラメータのうち値が無い（DB上nullなど）ものがあり、それがstringで返すパラメータの場合、そのままnullで返すか、型を合わせるために空文字で返すべきか、設計で悩んでいます。

現状、統一されていないため呼び出し側で判定して吸収しているのですが、どちらに合わせるのがよりベターでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

回答というよりも意見です。

- 空文字列が「あり得るデータ」であることに備えるなら、データが存在しない場合や意味を持たない場合はnullか0に統一するべきだと思います。
- 現状、空文字列があり得ないのならば、統一することを優先し、修正量が少ない方で決めるのも現実解だと思います。